# How to use dojo On with Dojox Searchbox?

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I am following this link http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/SearchBox.html and am trying to do the same in my app. The only difference is that I want to use "onSearch" event using "dojo On" but I am not able to read results, query, options that we get by default in the onSearch function.Please help me in solving this problem.

My HTML code:

```
 <input data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SearchBox" type="search" placeHolder="Search"
 data-dojo-props='store:store, searchAttr: "label", ignoreCase: true, pageSize:2'> 

<ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectList" jsId="list"></ul>
```

My JS code:

```
    define(["dojo/has",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-class",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/dom-style",
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/_base/Deferred",
    "dojo/topic",
    "dojo/_base/connect",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojox/mobile/SearchBox",
    "dojo/selector/acme"
    ],
   function(has,declare,lang,array,dom,domClass,domConstruct,query,domStyle,domAttr,on,Deferred,topic,connect,registry,MemoryStore,SearchBox)
   {

   declare("controllers.SearchController", [], {
           started:false,
           constructor : function(args) {
           WL.Logger.debug("SearchController created");
           lang.mixin(this,args);
           },

           start:function(){

               if(!this.started)
               {

               console.log("i am in SearchController.start");

               this.subscription();
               this.started = true;

               }
               },

           subscription:function(){

               store = new MemoryStore({data: [
                                               {label: "Alabama"},
                                               {label: "Alaska"},
                                               {label: "American Samoa"},
                                               {label: "Arizona"},
                                               {label: "Arkansas"},
                                               {label: "Kansas"},
                                               {label: "Kentucky"}
                                             ]});



               var searchbox=registry.byId("searchbox");
              on(searchbox.domNode,"search",lang.hitch(this,this.onSearch));       

           },

           onSearch: function (results, query, options) {

          //  this.onSearch = function () {};
            console.log(results);

        }

           });
   return controllers.SearchController;
   }
   );
```

Also, I am following this link [dojox/mobile/SearchBox 'onSearch' event runs twice on webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532565/dojox-mobile-searchbox-onsearch-event-runs-twice-on-webkit/17533426?noredirect=1#comment25500060_17533426) 
to use the workaround for dojox searchbox. How can I implement it in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** try to access widget events through DOM nodes. There is a difference between widgets and DOM nodes, and this is one of them. Also, because `dojo/on` can only be used with DOM nodes and DOM events, you cannot use it to handle the `onSearch` event.

Every widget has a [`on()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/mobile/SearchBox#1_9dojox_mobile_SearchBox_on) function that you can use to attach widget event handlers. For example:

```js
searchbox.on("search", lang.hitch(this, this.onSearch));
```

---

If the event runs twice, you can try doing something like this (you will probably have to rewrite this in your object oriented design):

```js
var myEventHandler = searchbox.on("search", lang.hitch(this, this.onSearch());
myEventHandler.remove();
```

According to the API documentation the return value of the `on()` function is `undefined`, but [this topic](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Widget-on-and-removing-handler-tp3822078p3823656.html) its stated that it returns an object containing a `remove()` function able to remove the event listener.

---

I don't think it's possible. If you want to retrieve data from your database/webservice, you could use the [`dojo/store/JsonRest`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) store (RESTful webservices) or you could implement your own store (or fetch the data and put it in a `dojo/store/Memory`).

Dojo chooses for an abstraction layer upon your data implementation called the store API. The advantages of these are that, because it's an abstraction layer, that you can use your store for multiple purposes (all Dijit widgets, Dojo mobile widgets, ...) work in a similar way that they use a store.

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitri for answering this. Your and Frode's answers solved my issue.

Comment: Dimitri.. I have one more question.. can we use dojox searchbox without using any store ? Suppose I want to only use the querystring from the searchbox to directly fetch data from database or using any web service... can this condition be achieved with dojox searchbox?

Comment: I updated my answer with your question. Short answer: No (at least I don't think so). If you want to use a service, you should make your own store or use one of the existing stores.

Comment: Actually, I am using IBM Worklight framework and want to use httpadapter feature of it to fetch the data from the webservice using the querystring user types in the searchbox and hit enter. My only need with Searchbox is to get the querystring and use the querystring inside onSearch function to fetch whole data using httpadapter. Is there any way to do this without dojo store?

Comment: Like I told you, no. You can put the data of the HttpAdapter in a memory store. There was also a project that acts as an adapter for the JSONStore in Worklight, more info about it can be found at https://github.com/ibm-dojo/dworklight.

Comment: JSONStore is not going to fulfill my requirement but Is it possible to get a textbox which looks similar to Searchbox(Search glass in it) and on hitting of enter...we reach to an eventhandler from where we can read the input text to fetch the data from service? How can we get this textbox which looks similar to searchbox?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning this part of your question:

> I am following this link [dojox/mobile/SearchBox 'onSearch' event runs twice on webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532565/dojox-mobile-searchbox-onsearch-event-runs-twice-on-webkit) to use the workaround for dojox searchbox. How can I implement it in my case?

I do not think such a workaround is needed. As I wrote in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21558531/1723384), as long as you have a store specified, SearchBox.onSearch() should be called only once.

In short: just do not apply this workaround, it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the event mistake pointed out by Dmitri, there's an issue with the order of execution.

When does Dojo parse your HTML? Do you have `parseOnLoad:true` in your `dojoConfig` (or `data-dojo-config`)?

When the parser reaches `data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SearchBox"`, it will try to instantiate a SearchBox widget. Because you have specified `store:store` in its properties, it will look for a variable called `store`.

Now, the `store` variable itself gets instantiated in your SearchController. So you have to make sure that `subscription()` is called **before** the parser runs. However, the `subscription()` method in turn tries to look for a widget called "searchbox". So the parser has to be called **before** `subscription()`. As you can tell, this isn't going to work :)

So you have to rewrite the SearchController a bit. For example, you can remove the `store:store` from `data-dojo-props`, and let the controller set it in the `subscription` method:

```
var store = new MemoryStore({data: [....]});
var searchbox = registry.byId("searchbox");

searchbox.set("store", store);
searchbox.on("search", lang.hitch(this, this.onSearch)); // See Dmitri's answer.
```

Comment: Hi Frode.. I have one more question though I have asked this question to Dimitri as well.. can we use dojox searchbox without using any store ? Suppose I want to only use the querystring from the searchbox to directly fetch data from database or using any web service... can this condition be achieved with dojox searchbox?

Comment: As already answered by Dimitri, no. More exactly, you need to either set the "store" property of the SearchBox, or its "list" property (see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/SearchBox.html#using-inline-option-tags). In both cases a store is used (in the second case it is created internally).